# understanding bias correction in ADAM algorithm

Tags: neural-networks, expected-value, bias-correction, adam

[image]

why is possible to approximate E[gi^2] with E[gt^2]? by the time we go to the t timestamp, we've already made weight updates, which mean gradients should be different as they are taken from different points in parameter space?

I guess we get error term(zeta) by making same approximation but are we really getting rid of that by doing the so-called bias correction, I don't think so

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question, it's not a duplicate one

Comment: In that case use the flag button above.

Comment: @user2974951, there's no need to flag. Editing a closed question bumps it into the reopen queue, where members of the community will decide whether to reopen it.